# How to color only some specific lines among many using ggplot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, lines

I have a gigante dataset that I need to plot to see the trajectory of my data.  I plotted a subset of it using the code:

```
ggplot(Trajectory, aes(x= Passage, y =Freq, group = SNV, color= SNV)) + geom_line()
```

and generated the plot - [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrQjO.jpg]

which is close to what I need. Now, I would like to change the colors of some of the lines (those that are present in all passages)

so I tried to use the ifelse function

```
ggplot(Trajectory, aes(x= Passage, y =Freq, group = SNV, color= ifelse(Trajectory==358, "red", ifelse(Trajectory==1212, "Blue", "white")))) +
  geom_line()
```

It didn't work and resulted in this error message.

> "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (1566): x, y, group, colour"

Any help will be more the appreciated.

The subset of my data that I used for plotting can be downloaded here https://cornell.box.com/s/vfe6144xbugdv805argpw8r5so98a73s

Comment: Thank you for your help guys.  I ended up subsetting my dataset creating a new table with the SNVs that I want to color differently.  Then, I overlaid the plots.  Here is the code if it helps someone else - library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=Trajectory) +
  geom_line(aes(x= Passage, y = Freq, group = SNV), colour ="grey57") +
  geom_line(data= P1toP5,
              aes(x= Passage, y = Freq, group = SNV), colour= "red1", linetype=2, size=1) +
  geom_line(data= P0toP5,
            aes(x= Passage, y = Freq, group = SNV), colour= "blue", size=1)   - Thanks a Bunch ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating another categorical variable with a unique level for the number of groups you want (SVN == 358, 1212, and so on) and then using `scale_color_manual` to specify the colors. Since I'm not going to download your data below is an example using the `iris` data.

```
library(tidyverse)
cols <- c('1' = 'red', '2' = 'blue', '3' = 'white')
iris <- iris %>% mutate(cat_var = as.character(rep(1:3, each = 50)))
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, col = cat_var)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try package `gghighlight`: https://yutani.rbind.io/post/2017-10-06-gghighlight/

In your case, this could be a good starting point:

```
library(gghighlight)
gghighlight_line(Trajectory,
                 aes(x= Passage, y = Freq, group = SNV),
                 Trajectory %in%  c(358,1212))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help guys.  I ended up subsetting my dataset creating a new table with the SNVs that I want to color differently.  Then, I overlaid the plots.

Here is the code if it helps someone else

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=Trajectory) +
  geom_line(aes(x= Passage, y = Freq, group = SNV), colour ="grey57") +
  geom_line(data= P1toP5,
              aes(x= Passage, y = Freq, group = SNV), colour= "red1", linetype=2, size=1) +
  geom_line(data= P0toP5,
            aes(x= Passage, y = Freq, group = SNV), colour= "blue", size=1)
```

Resulted plot is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K5WU.jpg)

-Thanks a Bunch ;)